# Interactive network graph for my website?

Tags: social-networking, neo4j, graph-databases, social-graph

I have a neo4j DB in my backend and I would like to display a subset of the graph to the user in a aesthetically pleasing and interactive fashion on the front-end. I'd like it to look quite compelling, close to [how gephi does it](http://www.google.com/search?q=gephi&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1600&bih=810), and so I need to choose the right technology for the job. Flash and Silverlight come to mind, but it's possible HTLM5 could be up to the job. Also Unity could be another option, but that might have a huge development cost.

Ideally I would like to use either an out of the box solution out there, or customize one that's been proven to work. The least ideal option is to implement it myself.

Would you guys be able to recommend an existing solution that would be a good match for my problem?

Comment: You may try the Sigma client (in Flash, controlled by Javascript):
http://ofnodesandedges.com/2011/10/06/sigma-client-demo.html It is used to visualize the GitHub community for instance:
http://ofnodesandedges.com/2011/06/20/stargit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the implementation of the visualization that is integrated in the Neo4j Server. That uses D4 and javascript (actually coffeescript) to render the graph.

Sources are here: https://github.com/neo4j/community/tree/master/server

You can also use [protoviz](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html) or other visualization [tools](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Visualization_options_for_graphs) for that.